# How can I use the Fortran Template Library?

Tags: templates, fortran

I'm trying to use the Fortran template library as show [here](https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl). I don't know if there's some needed installation in order to use it. Should I download the zip file ?
I created a file called task.F90_template as shown in the link and it contains:

```
T function task(self,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
&taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
T::self,ww,pas,cpt,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
&taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab
end function task
```

I don't understand also where to instantiate the template manually using the C preprocessor

```
#define T integer
#include "task.F90_template"

#define T real
#include "task.F90_template"
```

I want also to ask about the extension of the file tasks.F90_template since it doesn't get automatically colored.

Comment: You may also want to ask the authors of the project on the GitHub issues page: https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl/issues

Comment: @King Done but still no answer from the author..

Comment: It is a github project, clone the git repository. You can also just download the code, but cloning enables you fetching new versions. Then try what you wrote above and tell us if you encountered any problems. I suggest using `#undef T` otherwise you will get warnings. The extension is arbitrary. Colouring is controlled by your text editor, every editor is configured differently. Make a separate question and supply details about your editor.